# Mac HDD very slow running xcode and iOS Simulator

Tags: hard-drive, imac, xcode, ssd, xcode-simulator

We have a 500GB HDD on a iMac (21.5-inch, Mid 2014):

- 1.4 GHz Intel Core i5
- 8 GB 1600 MHz DDR3
- Intel HD Graphics 5000 1536 MB
- 224GB / 498GB available

We have spoken to Apple who said we cannot upgrade it to an SSD Drive, because it could break the motherboard.

We cannot afford a new Mac at the moment so I am looking for a solution to make these programs run faster.

Anyone have an tips/tricks to make it run faster?
Possibly install them all on an external Thunderbolt drive?

Comment: Hard drives are slow, SSDs are not. Upgrade to a SSD yourself.

Comment: Apple said it is not possible - it will break the motherboard

Comment: How do you know it's your hard drive that's causing Xcode and iOS simulator to run slowly? Can you please provide more details on your setup: (1) exact model of iMac; (2) RAM; (3) Free disk space; (4) version of macOS; (5) version of Xcode; (6) Anything else you can think of?

Comment: @Monomeeth I have put in an Edit to show the full specs above.
The reason I think its the hard drive is because I have a Macbook air with basically the same specs, but uses an SSD. Xcode and the simulator load in about 5 seconds compared to this iMac which can take up to 15 minutes?! Xcode is version 8.1 (Latest).

Comment: 5 seconds to 15 minutes is not SSD to Hard Disk you have some other problem

Comment: @Mark I've run black magic disk test on the computer and the read / right speeds of this iMac are 30-40 MB/S. Compared to my Macbook air which has speeds of 500-550MB/S.
This run time includes the code compilation. Do you think the iMac could be faulty?

Comment: Are you saying that both Xcode and the simulator each take about 15 mins to load on the iMac? Also, does it always take this long to load? What I mean is, once you've run Xcode and then quit it, how long does it take to launch again (assuming you have not restarted your iMac)? Also, once you've launched the simulator the first time you can keep it running in the background - is that what you're doing or do you keep closing it down and relaunching it?

Comment: Xcode usually takes about 2-3 minutes to boot up. Then running the simulator can take anything from 10-15 minutes depending if its iPad or iPhone. As a temporary solution open it each day and then don't close it. This makes the computer quite laggy though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the choice of internal storage for your model iMac was the worst possible, in that the 500GB hard drive you have installed was a 5400rpm model. These iMacs also came with a 1TB Fusion (or Hybrid) drive option as well as a 256GB SSD option, both of which are significantly faster (especially the SSD).

**Storage**

So, to answer your question as asked, you can in fact replace the hard drive in your model iMac if you want, although Apple does not 'officially' consider the storage (i.e. HDD/SSD) in any of the *Tapered Edge* aluminum iMacs to be upgradable. However, to be fair to Apple, upgrading this is extremely difficult and I would not recommend anyone having a go at it unless they're experienced or are very technically competent.

Based on your specs, your iMac has the model identifier **iMac14,4** (you can double-check this via the About This Mac option under the Apple Menu - click the System Report button). Instructions on upgrading your storage, along with videos, are available [here](https://eshop.macsales.com/shop/ssd/owc/imac-21.5-inch/2013-2014).

Remember though, this is not easy!

**RAM**

Your particular model iMac only came with 8GB RAM and this was soldered onto the Logic Board, so cannnot be removed and replaced. There are no additional memory slots. In other words, this cannot be upgraded whatsoever.

**External Storage**

In terms of external storage, the fastest option would be to use an SSD in an external enclosure connected to one of your Thunderbolt ports. Here are some [example options](https://eshop.macsales.com/shop/Thunderbolt/). However, you'd have to factor in the cost of the SSD and enclosure and decide whether that money would be better put towards a different Mac? The fact is that your model iMac is not really suited to heavy work as it's throttled by a lack of both processing power and RAM.

**Comparison test**

Also, as a test, I used a mid-2010 iMac with a 500GB hard drive installed and launched Xcode and compiled a few builds to the simulator and in all instances these were a lot quicker than the 15 mins you talk about. Of course, without compiling the same code this is not a fair comparison. However, this iMac did have 12GB of RAM installed and that is a 50% boost compared to what you will ever have for yours.

**My recommendations**

1. I would bite the bullet and start saving for another Mac.
2. Upgrading the internal hard drive is very difficult and I assume beyond your competency (no offense intended)!
3. In the meantime, I would ensure you keep your simulator running after first launch to significantly reduce subsequent builds etc.
4. You could also run an Apple Diagnostics Test to check your hardware to ensure there isn't some other undiagnsed problem. To do this, restart your iMac and immediately hold down the <kbd>D</kbd> key. When prompted, run the tests. If you get the option to run an extended test, select this as well. Note this may take some time to run!

Any problems/questions, let me know.

Comment: Thanks @Monomeeth. As you said I think we are going to have to bite the bullet for a few months and then purchase a new mac. Cheers for the conclusive answer!